# reading xml from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to read xml from the url(well its not url its restful service) and below is my code. I dont know what the problem is but Iam unable to read the xml from url. I am getting error and I am not getting any data..

```
    string soap = "";
if (fPortalGuid != string.Empty)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://cramapp-dt-02s.cable.comcast.com:8158/restfulqueryservice/queryservice/getrequestdetails?api_key=......&request_id=33ebc6e9-9def-4f39-adf9-bba2edef3b54") as HttpWebRequest;
    //request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("rolland", "409cleaner");
    //request.ContentType = "application / json; charset = utf - 8";
    request.Method = "POST";

    using (Stream stm = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
        {
            stmw.Write(soap);
        }
    }
    // Get response  
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        // Get the response stream  
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        // Console application output  
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

and the xml looks like this[image: xml file image]

Comment: You sure your interface accepts POST requests?  Try doing a GET.

Comment: How did you get the XML you are showing in your screenshot? The message above the xml, "The XML file does not appear..." is just the browser warning you it's showing the XML with an internal style sheet, not an error with the web service. If you are getting an exception in your C# code, please provide that.

Comment: when i used GET , I am getting error like "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type"

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan when i copy and paste the url in the browser that's what I am getting. I am not getting any exception.

Answer (score 0):

This line may makes error

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://cramapp-dt-02s.cable.comcast.com:8158/restfulqueryservice/queryservice/getrequestdetails?api_key=......&request_id=33ebc6e9-9def-4f39-adf9-bba2edef3b54") as HttpWebRequest;
```

Because the url in the create function is not avaiable too access (too long so has ... for shout display), try locate and paste the full link or this link :

```
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml
```

Comment: Not too long; just hiding his api key.